# Make [build.gradle.kts] a synonym of [gradle-kotlin-dsl]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I think those two have the same topic.
I would prefer to keep [gradle-kotlin-dsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradle-kotlin-dsl) rather than [build.gradle.kts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build.gradle.kts), as that is how the [project is called](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl) on GitHub.

Answer (score 12):

To clarify this request, here is some information I dug up.

- [build.gradle.kts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build.gradle.kts) only has 4 questions at the moment;
- all of those questions are **already tagged** [gradle-kotlin-dsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradle-kotlin-dsl) (which has 18 questions in total);
- [`build.gradle.kts`](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/blob/master/build.gradle.kts) is a file in the project that can be included to use it;
- [gradle-kotlin-dsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradle-kotlin-dsl) does have a tag wiki (although minimal), whereas [build.gradle.kts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build.gradle.kts) does not.

Synonymizing [build.gradle.kts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build.gradle.kts) → [gradle-kotlin-dsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradle-kotlin-dsl) makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

This has now been completed, enjoy!